Unusual printer deployment
Does anyone know of any method, or software, that will change what printers a user has based on what specific computer they're logged into? Or are we just stuck with manually installing sets of printers for our users?
We have 130 printers spread across 13 locations. All printers are installed on a print server. We allow all users access to all printers.
Our helpdesk spends a significant amount of time each day installing printers from the print server for our end users. We want users to have sets of printers based on what computer they are logged into.
For example, if a user is on the teller line in Detroit on Monday, they log into a teller computer in Detroit and receive the teller printers at the Detroit location. Tuesday they will be a loan officer in Omaha and when they log into the loan officer computer in Omaha, they will receive the loan officer printers in the Omaha location. Wednesday they will be a loan officer in Detroit, when they log into the loan officer computer in Detroit they should have the loan officer printers at the Detroit location.
Most of the deployment options I've been able to find focus on deploying printers via GPO based on user group membership. But in my testing, that means that a specific set of printers follows the user to whatever location they're at on whatever computer they log into. For example, if an Omaha teller line user goes to Detroit to be a loan officer, they'd still have the Omaha teller line printers installed on the Detroit loan officer computer. We don't want that. We want users' printers to change based on what computer they're logged into.
I've seen suggestions of deploying printers based on AD site membership, but that still doesn't seem to allow targeting subsets of computers in the site.
I've trialed Papercut's Print Deploy feature, but it's been giving me trouble. For some reason, it won't allow me to create print queues. The print queue copy from an existing machine can't find printers installed on our workstations for some reason. Plus, it will only allow deployment of sets of printers based on subnet, not what computer the user is logged into.

Are you wanting, essentially, only a single printer installed to each computer, and for any user logged on to that computer to have that as their default printer?

It looks like prnmgr.vbs is still a thing and there's an answer for this at Superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/278575/how-do-i-install-a-network-printer-for-all-users-on-a-windows-7-computer

@music2myear Thank you for that information. We want to install several printers per computer that all users will have access to on each computer.

What identifiers do you have associated with the computers that a script or other tool may be able to use to identify where the computer is located and therefore which printers need to be installed? Computer names, OU membership, or other attributes, could be used by a script that checks for and installs printers based on these factors.

@music2myear No, we don't have many identifiers linked with our computers. We have some broad divisions based on the type of work they do, but not location. If we can't find anything else, the scripting you pointed out would be sufficient I think. We would write the scripts and then just run them on the computer(s) as we deploy them.

I believe Print&Share v3.x or Print&Share CQ is capable of this.

It feels as though you're putting in a lot of manual effort when you could be implementing a system that can largely run itself once you've set it up.
If you don't have identifiers in the computer names, you can use AD security groups and a GPO.

Create an AD Security Group for each location a given user could work in.
Create a GPO pushing printer(s) (and not changing the default) for each location. These can all be in a single GPO, with printers deployed using Targeting filtering on the user's Security Group memberships.
Assign groups to appropriate users.
Profit.

Going forward, the helpdesk would handle subsequent requests by simply assigning security groups for the not-yet-assigned locations to users as they report they are missing the printers they need.
This makes the system handle itself going forward. Exceptions are handled as exceptions, and most people, most of the time, just find their printers installed on their computers and ready for them to use as soon as they need.

It's a great idea, but I think that the GPO method would still be too slow. About 1/3 of our employees change locations daily, a subset can change locations multiple times a day. It's not the same users all the time either. Our workforce is insanely mobile and change locations at a mindboggling rate sometimes. They would call helpdesk to get their security group changed and wait for the printers to show up. Users often don't call until they need to print something for a customer. At the moment helpdesk is a bit protected because so many users are already set up on dozens of workstations.

It would only be "slow" the first time. Any groups they're already members of would enforce the printer install at login. Also, you're not changing security groups, you're just adding groups when necessary. The only "slow" part would be if they're already logged in and a new group needs to be added, after which you'd have to wait the GPO enforcement timeout (or run gpupdate /force after a couple minutes).

The downside of this is that they'd have EVERY printer installed on each computer. But they can set default printers, and because your GPO isn't overwriting or setting defaults, that would, once again, only be a problem the first time they logged in to a new computer.

You can deploy per-computer GPO. This way when a user connects to a computer in Detroit, the computer has the printers from the Detroit office, and when a user connects to another location the printers are correct.
I did this setup for medical offices, where doctors and specialists often change clinics.
The only drawback is you have to tell users to change their default printer based on their needs when they sit at new computer.
You have two places where you can configure this:
First method: Printer deployment settings:

Second method:

I used the second method. It creates a local print queue and connects to a share for the first install to get the correct drivers.
I did that way as many clinics didn't have a local print server, so the print queue gets added as TCP/IP direct, unloading any VPN traffic for print jobs.
The first method is better if you have local print server at each site, as it's more central to the print server.
Note that the first computer login to the network will be slow after you set that GPO, as it will be installing the necessary drivers for the assigned printers, but afterwards login times should return to normal.
